# Filter duplicates from list based on Levenshtein distance

Tags: python, list, indexing, levenshtein-distance

Let's say that I have a list of JSONs like in the example. Of those that have duplicate `title` attribute (as determined by scoring over a certain threshold of Levenshtein distance), I'd like to filter out the duplicates that do not have the minimum value in another attribute (`sourceRank`).

Here was my idea for how to do this, however, the indexing is broken. What is the most efficient way to accomplish this?

```
articles = [
    {'_source': {'title':'Cyber Monday UK Apple deals 2018: MacBooks, iPhones, iPads and Apple Watches', 'sourceRank':4.0},
    {'_source': {'title':'Cyber Monday UK Apple deals 2018: MacBooks, iPhones, iPads and Apple Watches', 'sourceRank':1.0},
    {'_source': {'title':'Cyber Monday UK Apple deals 2018: MacBooks, iPhones, iPads and Apple Watches', 'sourceRank':2.0},
    {'_source': {'title':'Apple Pay Apple Pay Launches in Belgium and Kazakhstan', 'sourceRank':1.0},
    {'_source': {'title':'APPLE : Supreme Court weighs antitrust dispute over Apple App Store', 'sourceRank':3.0},
]

print len(articles)
print [a['_source']['title'] for a in articles]

def levenshtein_distance(s1, s2):
    if len(s1) > len(s2):
        s1, s2 = s2, s1

    distances = range(len(s1) + 1)
    for i2, c2 in enumerate(s2):
        distances_ = [i2+1]
        for i1, c1 in enumerate(s1):
            if c1 == c2:
                distances_.append(distances[i1])
            else:
                distances_.append(1 + min((distances[i1], distances[i1 + 1], distances_[-1])))
        distances = distances_
    return distances[-1]

indices = []
for i1, a1 in enumerate(articles):
    for i2, a2 in enumerate(articles):
        if levenshtein_distance(a1['_source']['title'], a2['_source']['title']) > .8:
            if a1['_source']['sourceRank'] > a2['_source']['sourceRank']:
                indices += [i1]
            else:
                indices += [i2]
articles = [i for j, i in enumerate(articles) if j not in indices]

print len(articles)
print [a['_source']['title'] for a in articles]
```

Comment: Please clarify per the posting standards: [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  Exactly how is the indexing "broken"?  Show your tracing output, and what you expected.  Slipping in a couple of `print` statements to show the problem can help a *lot*.

Comment: You JSON elements are missing their ending } and your last element should not have a trailing comma

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The gist of your question seems to be removing duplicate titles from your list while ensuring the remaining title has the lowest sourceRank.
I don't know how high the sourRank values could potentially be, so I just took a stab at 100000 for a sentinel value.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import itertools


articles = [
    {'_source': {'title':'Cyber Monday UK Apple deals 2018: MacBooks, iPhones, iPads and Apple Watches', 'sourceRank':4.0}},
    {'_source': {'title':'Cyber Monday UK Apple deals 2018: MacBooks, iPhones, iPads and Apple Watches', 'sourceRank':1.0}},
    {'_source': {'title':'Cyber Monday UK Apple deals 2018: MacBooks, iPhones, iPads and Apple Watches', 'sourceRank':2.0}},
    {'_source': {'title':'Apple Pay Apple Pay Launches in Belgium and Kazakhstan', 'sourceRank':1.0}},
    {'_source': {'title':'APPLE : Supreme Court weighs antitrust dispute over Apple App Store', 'sourceRank':3.0}}
]

def reducer(iter_):
    max_rank = 100000
    retval = None
    for value in iter_:
        current_rank = value["_source"]["sourceRank"]
        if current_rank < max_rank:
            max_rank = current_rank
            retval = value
    return retval


for title, _source in itertools.groupby(articles, lambda x: x["_source"].get("title")):
    print(reducer(_source))
```

Comment: How would I save the result of this as a variable, `articles`. Unclear to me based on the way it is written.

Comment: Nvmd:  `[reducer(_source) for title, _source in itertools.groupby(articles, lambda x: x["_source"].get("title"))]`

Comment: Beat me to it @ChrisC. Quick on the draw